# problems with downloading Winehq on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine, google-chrome

I was following the instructions on the https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for winehq installation. When I executed

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
```

a blank line appeared with no response and it brought me back to the input line. I thought maybe it worked and then I executed `sudo apt update` and it said

```
Malformed entry 6 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (component).
```

Can anyone help?

```
deb-src https://archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu   xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Also if I may add I am running a chroot

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the output of `grep -vE '^(#.*)?$' /etc/apt/sources.list`? That shows all non-empty and not commented lines of this file.

Comment: I'm sorry im new to this kind of stuff so can you explain what you want me to do?

Comment: Just copy that command above in a terminal, run it, and copy its output to paste it here into your question again.

Comment: I got that and I inputted again and got noting back

Comment: Weird. Just paste the whole content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file here then. Also please use code formatting for this in your question.

Comment: Change the line from `deb-src https://archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu` to `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` then leaving the rest of that line alone.  In the sources https does not work for the canonical or ubuntu lines.